# Parsing specific contents in a file

Tags: python

I have a file that looks like this

```
    !--------------------------------------------------------------------------DISK
    [DISK]
    DIRECTION  =  'OK'
    TYPE       =  'normal'

    !------------------------------------------------------------------------CAPACITY
    [CAPACITY]
    code            =    0
    ID          =   110
```

I want to read sections [DISK] and [CAPACITY].. there will be more sections like these. I want to read the parameters defined under those sections.

I wrote a following code:

```
file_open = open(myFile,"r")
all_lines = file_open.readlines()
count = len(all_lines)
file_open.close()
my_data = {}
section = None
data = ""
for line in all_lines:
  line = line.strip()                               #remove whitespace
  line = line.replace(" ", "")      
  if len(line) != 0:               # remove white spaces between data        
      if line[0] == "[":
          section = line.strip()[1:]
          data = ""
      if line[0] !="[":
          data += line + "," 
          my_data[section] = [bit for bit in data.split(",") if bit != ""]
print my_data
key = my_data.keys()
print key
```

Unfortunately I am unable to get those sections and the data under that. Any ideas on this would be helpful.

Comment: The file looks like a normal "ini" file, but with a custom comment introducing character. You may want to use the Python standard [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) module as a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [others already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14975535/142637), you should be able to use the `ConfigParser` module.

---

Nonetheless, if you want to implement the reading/parsing yourself, you should split it up into two parts.

Part 1 would be the parsing at file level: splitting the file up into blocks (in your example you have two blocks: `DISK` and `CAPACITY`).

Part 2 would be parsing the blocks itself to get the values.

You know you can ignore the lines starting with `!`, so let's skip those:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = [l for l in f.readlines() if not l.startswith('!')]
```

Next, read the lines into blocks:

```
def partition_by(l, f):
    t = []
    for e in l:
        if f(e):
            if t: yield t
            t = []
        t.append(e)
    yield t

blocks = partition_by(content, lambda l: l.startswith('['))
```

and finally read in the values for each block:

```
def parse_block(block):
    gen = iter(block)
    block_name = next(gen).strip()[1:-1]
    splitted = [e.split('=') for e in gen]
    values = {t[0].strip(): t[1].strip() for t in splitted if len(t) == 2}
    return block_name, values

result = [parse_block(b) for b in blocks]
```

That's it. Let's have a look at the result:

```
for section, values in result:
    print section, ':'
    for k, v in values.items():
        print '\t', k, '=', v
```

output:

```
DISK :
        DIRECTION = 'OK'
        TYPE = 'normal'
CAPACITY :
        code = 0
        ID = 110
```

Comment: It really *is* a pain that the comment characters are hardcoded in 2.7.3 :P

Comment: @DemianBrecht Yes it is. I also looked at the source of `ConfigParser` in hope of a quick fix, but I was disappointed by the monster-`_read`-function too :-) Nice to see it was improved in python 3.

Comment: Thanks that works like a charm. I have a small question. How do I add the values of block to a list e.g. DISK =['OK', 'normal']. I am having trouble accessing the values. Any thoughts?

Comment: `result` is a list of tuples, where each tuple is a `string` (name of block) and a `dict` (config keys and values). If you want e.g. a `dict` of 'name of block' and 'values of config', you could use something like `dic_of_lists = {s: v.values() for s,v in result}`, which would then be `{'DISK': ["'OK'", "'normal'"], 'CAPACITY': ['0', '110']}`

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to make a small change to the text file? If you can make it look like this (only changed the comment character):

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------DISK
[DISK]
DIRECTION  =  'OK'
TYPE       =  'normal'

#------------------------------------------------------------------------CAPACITY
[CAPACITY]
code            =    0
ID          =   110
```

Then parsing it is trivial:

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('filename')
```

And getting data looks like this:

```
(Pdb) parser
<ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser instance at 0x100468dd0>
(Pdb) parser.get('DISK', 'DIRECTION')
"'OK'"
```

**Edit based on comments:**

If you're using <= 2.7, then you're a little SOL.. The only way really would be to subclass `ConfigParser` and implement a custom `_read` method. Really, you'd just have to copy/paste everything in `Lib/ConfigParser.py` and edit the values in line 477 (2.7.3):

`if line.strip() == '' or line[0] in '#;': # add new comment characters in the string`

**However**, if you're running 3'ish (not sure what version it was introduced in offhand, I'm running 3.4(dev)), you may be in luck: `ConfigParser` added the `comment_prefixes` `__init__` param to allow you to customize your prefix:

`parser = ConfigParser(comment_prefixes=('#', ';', '!'))`

Comment: Thanks. When I do replace the "!" with "$" ( I cannot use #). I do get MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.

Comment: According to the docs, ``#`` and ``;`` are valid comment identifiers. If you can use either of those, you should be good.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately its not possible to use either or # or ,. In that case is there any way to do this without configparser?

Comment: just remove the comments first?
data = '\n'.join(line for line in data.split('\n') if '!----' not in line])

Comment: @matt possbile, since you need a file or file-like object for `ConfigParser`, you'll have to use the `io`-module: `parser.readfp(io.BytesIO(data))`

Answer (score -1):

If the file is not big, you can load it and use Regexes to find parts that are of interest to you.